# Save docker image with maven fabric8 plugin

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8

I want to include in my pom.xml some bits to save a docker image that was built, this is what i put in the  sections of the fabric8 docker mvn plugin.

```
<execution>
                        <id>save</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
```

and i also included this property like shown in the fabric8 doc

```
<properties>
               <docker.save.alias>image</docker.save.alias>
</properties>
```

But when i do mvn package i dont see any image.tar. Also is it possible to package some other file with the image tar in another archive ?

Comment: What tar file are you expecting? A Docker tar image that can be imported or a tar of the jar + Dockerfile that can be externally built as an image?

Comment: A docker tar image and if possible a tar containing that tar plus some ressources of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can have two kind of tar archives expoerted with d-m-p:

- Use [docker:save](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:save) to export the Docker image itself. This is a tar archive containing all image layers and has the same format as the archive that you get with `docker save`. You can use this archive with `docker import` to import this image again.
- [docker:source](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:source) can be used to save the Docker tar which is sent to a Docker daemon for creating the image. This archive contains the build context (i.e. all files which you `ADD` or `COPY` with a Dockerfile) and the Dockerfile itself.

Both goals can be bound to execution phases. `docker:save` does not have a default execution phase, but `docker:source` has `package` as its default phase (and are hence created just before install if bound.

So for your example to bind the `docker:save` goal to the package phase you need to configure the phase explicitly for the `save` goal (which was missing in your example)

```xml
<execution>
   <id>save</id>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
     <goal>build</goal>
     <goal>save</goal>
   </goals>
</execution>
```